# How to do dop-down menu like android gmail?

Tags: ios, xcode, drop-down-menu

I wan to do a drop-down menu looks like android gmail. You can see the picture as this pic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoUYr.png), the green area is not full width size of screen. All I can find sample was slide menu, even gmail version on iphone was not the same with android. How to do that in iOS?

thanks!

Comment: Drop down? I'm checking the app on an android phone and thats the native side menu you have for android. When ever I need a side menu on my apps I use **MMDrawerController** https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController. Would that do the trick? If its not good for you make me know so I can give a more complex answer that will fit you.

Comment: thanks! But I want the menu is under the navigation bar, not a slide sidebar menu.You can see that http://i.imgur.com/PtyQI35.png. I want to click red area and then green area show up. The width of green area is not full fit the screen, a part of it is translucent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you mention it thats a pretty cool menu, I did it here in a sample protect:

https://github.com/Plasher/SideMenu

Of course there's no delegates or anything in it. If you or users here believe its a nice menu I might go and make it better.

Comment: Cool! this slide action is what I want to do. Could it support UItableview in menu?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Just set the SideMenuViewController as a UITableViewController and you're good to go. Don't forget to up vote, cheers.